# Inserting elements into a linked list C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

Given the EleList class how do I go about writing the implementation of the Insert() function?
I've never really used pointers so this simple problem really has me stumped, I would appreciate a link to relevant learning material if possible.

```
class EleList
    {
    public:
        EleList( char cData )
        : m_cData(cData)
        , m_Left(0)
        , m_Right(0)
        {
        }
    
        static void Insert( EleList* InsertEle, 
            EleList* InsertPos);
    
    private:
        char m_cData;
        EleList* m_Left;
        EleList* m_Right;
    };
    
    // Insert() function
    void EleList::Insert( EleList* InsertEle, 
            EleList* InsertPos)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Draw a picture of the list and the new item off to the side a bit as a bunch of circles connected with lines. Then, step-by-step, move the lines so they link in the new item. Make sure you maintain a path forward and backward through the list at all times, because if you lose where one of the lines pointed too soon, you've broken the list. Take good notes on what you did because the notes will become your code.

Comment: Here's a simple way to figure out how to do this, and it never fails to work. Just take out a blank sheet of paper. Write down using short, simple sentences in plain English, a step-by-step process of doing this. When done, [call your rubber duck for an appointment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). We don't write entire programs for other people, on Stackoverflow. We always refer such questions to your rubber duck. After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++. Mission accomplished!

Comment: Check this out for a generic linked list implementation: https://eecs280staff.github.io/notes/17_Linked_Lists.html

Answer (score 1):

Pointers seem a bit tricky in the beginning. I strongly recommend you to draw in paper the algorithm you want to implement when it involves data structures and pointers, before doing any code. A linked list is a good way to start to learn them.

Into the implementation you can take several approaches, because you have to consider different cases:

- Inserting at the beginning of a list or in an empty list: we create the node and swap the left pointer with the head of the list.
- Inserting in the middle of a list: we iterate the list with an auxiliary pointer until the desired position, we create the new node and redirect the necessary pointers (the ones of the new node and the ones from the neighbour nodes).
- Inserting at the end of the list: we iterate until the last element, create the new node and attach them to each other with the pointers.

You can try to implement one and from there try another. If you are learning, it doesn't have to be perfect, it has to make you understand how pointers and data structures work.

I'm sure you will find [this link](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/linked-list/) useful, it's very complete and has an extensive example in code.

Comment: A few notes: The class in the question is conflating the node and the list, and is the reason for the goofiness of the `static` member function and the exposed nodes.  There is a good case to be made for a non-`static` version of insert as a `private` member of a list class. If inserting at the end is a common behaviour, add a tail pointer to track the end of the list. Otherwise, check if using the same method as the insert in middle of the list's not found case is good enough. No sense having a special rule and more code unless you have to.

Comment: @user4581301 You are right, I overlooked that the function is `private`, I will adapt my answer. Also, when I talk about the different cases I don't mean that they should be in separate functions or be checked always, only that they must be considered according to the implementation to prevent null pointer accesses.